# String Split in R

Tags: r

I have following column in my data set.

```
TENURE

April 30, 1789 – March 3,1797
March 4, 1797 - March 3, 1801
March 4, 1841 - April 4, 1841[Died]
March 4, 1881 - September 19, 1881[Assassinated]
January 20, 1969 - August 9, 1974[Resigned]
...
...
```

I have load the dataset into a dataframe with one of this column named TENURE.
Now I want to make two more columns names "Start" and "End" based on the TENURE.Those two new columns would then be included into my dataframe.
The result of two columns would look like this

```
Start   End
1789    1797
1797    1901
1841    1841
1881    1881
1969    1974
```

So far I have done following

```
require(XML)
require(stringr)
urlPresidents<-"http://www.theholidayspot.com/july4/us_presidents.htm"
presidents <- readHTMLTable(urlPresidents,which = 3,
                            skip.rows = 1,header = TRUE,
                            stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
yearList <- str_split(presidents$TENURE,pattern = ",",n = 1)
```

I am strucked and not getting how to proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `str_extract_all` and match all for digits number, in this case it works.

```
r <- str_extract_all(presidents$TENURE, "\\d{4}")
df <- data.frame(start = sapply(r, "[", 1), end = sapply(r, "[", 2))
head(df)
##   start  end
## 1  1789 1797
## 2  1797 1801
## 3  1801 1809
## 4  1809 1817
## 5  1817 1825
## 6  1825 1829
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it can be done in three steps:

1. Devide 2date-string into two parts

   ```
   a <- c('March 4, 1797 - March 3, 1801','March 4, 1841 - April 4, 1841[Died]')
   a_devided <- strsplit(a,' - ')
   ```
2. Convert strings into date objects

   ```
   a_devided_dates <- lapply(a_devided, function(x) as.Date( x, '%B %d, %Y') )
   ```
3. Extract years from dates:

   ```
   lapply(a_devided_dates, function(x) format(x, '%Y'))
   ```